# IE 7 CSS Display Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

There is a defect in the following website where the search text box doesn't align correctly with the button, all other browsers seen fine. Can't figure out what is causing it can anyone help please?

http://www.martrainhaulage.com/

Comment: looks ok to me (Opera) pls give more info on "doesn't align"

Comment: It is an IE7 specific issue type the url into here http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php (ie7)

Comment: Glad to see you solved the problem on IE7. Could you please tell us what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/**
Maybe add a **width** on floating `header div.search`?

```
header div.search {
  width: 211px; /* approx */
}
```

**2/**
Or does this test code do anything? (**not** for production!)

```
<!--[if IE 7]><style type="text/css">
  * { zoom: 1; /* and even less production-ready: position: relative; */ }
</style><![endif]-->
```

It'll give every element the hasLayout. If it solves your problem as is, you must then hunt down which element(s) really need(s) hasLayout to display properly. Could be form, its parent or one of its children ... Then only give hasLayout to this element.

**3/**
You could also use **display: inline-block** on each three children of form (without whitespace in HTML code between them) and tell IE6/7

```
 each_element_with_display_inlineblock {
   display: inline;
   zoom: 1; /* or nothing if it already has a width, height or any property giving it hasLayout */
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm... it's rather hard for me to tell how this can be fixed but here's what I've tried.

First off, these kind of bugs seem to more often than not be the result of not enough width applied to an element.  Changing the `#container` width to 950px fixes it partially (for IE 9 running as IE 7).  Then changing the `float:left` on `header div.search .txtSearch` and `header div.search label` to `float:right`.  Lastly changing the markup to correctly align the form elements should fix the odd issue.